# Suggestion for parallelizing an application?

Tags: c++, pthreads, parallel-processing

I have to parallelize some c++ application for my college project. But, I could not think of any application that is not very huge and can be parallelizes. I would like suggestions from you guys.

Please suggest me some serial application that I can parallelize. Please point me to some link where I can get code for some (not very huge) application that I can then parallelize.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do some Fourier-Transformation. There are gazillion good reasons to do one and it can be parallelized. Edith reminded me that if a Fourier is too complicated, do a Discrete Cosine Transform. Much easier to code. Just google "DCT" and you will find examples and explanations.

Answer (score 1):

A simple game of life or DES data encryption application would be good candidates for things that arent that huge but can be used to demonstrate parallel programming

Answer (score 1):

Matrix multiplication?

http://www.mcs.anl.gov/~itf/dbpp/text/node45.html

Answer (score 0):

You could search for existing programs whose problem qualify as embarrassingly parallel. [Here are some examples from wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarassingly_parallel#Examples)

Answer (score 0):

I always like to split the logging out into separate threads and turn it into a producer consumer thread. You can have multiple consumer threads (going to different files or the same file). You can also do this for other resources like socket reading etc... if the processing on the input data is hight.